# How can I access in .htaccess keys and values in query_string to use them in the changed url?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I am trying to convert a url with get parameters

```
localhost:8080/goto/?fruits=1&apples=2
```

into

```
localhost:8080/fruits/1/apples/2
```

With the following commands:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !apples [NC]
```

I can validate if the accessed url is having the key apples, fruits or whatever get parameter is attached to distinguish between multiple urls with different keys like berrys=1 or melons=7 etc.

With the following commands

```
RewriteRule ^ fruits/([^/]*)/apples/([^/]*)$ goto/index.php?fruits=$1&apples=$2 [L]
```

I can change the url localhost:8080/fruits/1/apples/2 to localhost:8080/fruits/1/apples/2

How can I optimize the commands in the RewriteCond to use multiple keys and values as $1, $2 etc in the RewriteRule to not hardcode multiple lines? Like not:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !apples [NC]
RewriteRule ^fruits/([^/]*)/apples/([^/]*)$ goto/index.php?fruits=$1&apples=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !melons [NC]
RewriteRule ^fruits/([^/]*)/melons/([^/]*)$ goto/index.php?fruits=$1&melons=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !berrys [NC]
RewriteRule ^fruits/([^/]*)/berrys/([^/]*)$ goto/index.php?fruits=$1&berrys=$3 [L] ....
```

Comment: I foresee a lot of issues in your future with this approach.  The biggest of which is that the url parameters do not have to follow a consistent order.  I would abandon .htaccess and create another url for /goto in your application that does the redirecting (301 Moved Permanently) in PHP.

Comment: I will get the keys and values as json array of object trough the database via php into an angular application. I will secure access post, patch, put, update and delete requests via jwt. I am trying to pull the keys, fruits, berrys, melons and apples and values 1, 2, 3 etc. from the get parameters. Wouldn't that be possible? Or where could issues arise?

Is it possible to create virtual folders with php?

Comment: Ah, you need an application request router to map your incoming requests to a controller.  I would just pick a framework and use what they ship to do this.  There are 100s of frameworks to choose from.  If you want to patch something together, take a look at [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) or maybe [Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/routing).  If you want to use htaccess, just rewrite /goto to a php file and have that file push the redirect.

Comment: Thank you @AlexBarker very much for your advice.I have now implemented all virtual folders at the .htaccess file and can now implement the routing via PHP.